# Django Rest Serializers: Return data of related field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I created models which are `Contracts` and `ContractItems`. `ContractItems` table contains a foreign key attribute of `Contracts` table. I need to return `Contracts` with their relevant `ContractItems`.

I implemented a serializer like it.

```
class ContractSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contract
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

I could not get `ContractItems` to relevant `Contract`.

Could anyone suggest any way to get `Contracts` with their relevant `ContractItems`? And also One `Contract` can have many `ContractItems`.

Answer (score 3):

```
class ContractItemSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ContractItems
        fields = '__all__'  

class ContractSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    contract_items  =  serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Contract
        fields = ('id', 'name')

    def get_contract_items(self, obj):
        qs = obj.related_name.all()
        return  ContractItemSerializer(qs, many=True).data
```

Comment: "qs = obj.related_name.all()" please use the related name that you used in ContractItem Model for the foreign key `Contract` this will get all the contract item related to a contract object

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you try this too. You can get the related objects serialized too.

```
class ContractItemSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ContractItems
        exclude = ()
class ContractSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    contract_items  =  ContractItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)    
    class Meta:
        model = Contract
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

Check this for reference: [Example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#example)